# Why Do Some Delphi Components Require "AOwner: TComponent" To Construct Them?

Tags: delphi, vcl

It seems completely irrelevant to require a TComponent as an owner to instantiate an object of some kind.  Why are there so many Delphi components that require this?

For example, TXMLDocument requires a TComponent object to instantiate.

Why is this and if there's a good reason, what should I be using in there to "do the right thing"?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The owner component is supposed to manage all its owned components. The owned components gets destroyed automatically when the owner is destroyed.

This helps the developer who just drags components from the tool-palette, drops them on the form and just hooks up the events to get his work done without worrying about managing the lifetime of the components.

The form is the owner of all components dropped on it. The Application object is owner of the form. When the app is closed the Application object is destroyed which in turn destroys the forms and all the components.

But the owner is not really necessary when a components is created. If you pass Nil to the parameter, the component will be created without an owner and in this case it will be your responsibility to manage the component's lifetime.

Comment: Great answer.  So if I wanted to manage the lifetime myself, how would I make sure an object is destroyed when I'm done with it?

Comment: @prapin: Slight correction is necessary: The Application object is only owner of a form if the form has been created with Application.CreateForm(), or when Application has been passed to Create as AOwner. A form could be owned by another form, or any other component for that matter.

Comment: @Dave: Following SO questions deal with object ownership: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398137/what-is-the-best-way-to-do-nested-try-and-finally-statement-in-delphi#399860, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415958/how-to-automatically-free-classes-objects#415990

Answer (score 9):

All TComponent descendents require Owner, it is defined in TComponent constructor.
The Owner component is responsible to destroy all the Owned components.

if you want to control the life time, you can pass nil as parameter.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add some extra information.

Each control also has a parent. (A TWinControl). Where the owner takes care of the lifetime, the parent takes care of showing the object.

For example a form has a panel and the panel has a button. In that case, the form owns the panel and the button. But the form is the parent of the panel and the panel is the parent of the button.

Comment: Yes, but not all components (TComponent) are controls (TControl).  TControl descends from TComponent.  A component that is not a control does not have a parent.

Comment: Also worth noting is that if you destroy a parent, the children will get destroyed, too, even if they're not owned by the parent.

Answer (score 3):

There is also something else to be aware of. I have used more than a couple of third party components which **rely** on an Owner component being passed in the Constructor Create, and if you pass in Nil will throw an exception/AV.

The net result is that these components will work fine when you use the visually within the IDE but cause problems when they are created at run-time.

The cause of these problems is, in a sense, bad design. Nothing in the rules state you cannot/should not pass in NIL as the aOwner parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You shoudl use this for two reasons:
- the ownership mechanism stands also as a kind of garbage collecting system
- the ownership mechanism is important in Delphi serialization process (Stream.ReadComponent/WriteComponent etc).

Answer (score 0):

An Owner parameter is only needed for `TComponent` descendants, as it is a parameter of the `TComponent` constructor.  All components that are accessible at design-time for dropping on `TForm`, `TFrame`, and `TDataModule` classes are `TComponent` descendants (which includes `TXMLDocument`).