# What argument to use for AOwner when constructing TComponent Descendents?

Tags: delphi, rad-studio

When I want to create a `TComponent` descendent using the Create method in delphi we must pass a parameter :

```
className.Create(AOwner)
```

where `AOwner` is of type `TComponent`

From what i know it accepts any one of three parameter(in default create cases)

```
Nil,Self, application
```

I did't quite understood when to use which.

Can someone please elaborate on same.

Comment: It depends on the class.  Which class are you asking about.  They can all be different.  Are you specifically talking about descendents of `TComponent`?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes TComponent specifically

Comment: Also depends on context.. Did you read the [docs](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TComponent.Owner) already? Also [this](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.Classes.TComponent.Create).

Comment: Also you can search for and find similar questions, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/474448/why-do-some-delphi-components-require-aowner-tcomponent-to-construct-them) one.

Comment: Or, my standard advice: by reading a good book about Delphi programming, you learn how the language works and you get the big picture combined with the subtle details. It is much harder to truly learn a new language by simply googling one particular issue at a time. Much harder.