# Extract nested try/finally blocks

Tags: delphi, refactoring, extract, try-finally

How would you "extract" nested try/finally blocks from a routine into a reusable entity? Say I have

```
procedure DoSomething;
var
  Resource1: TSomeKindOfHandleOrReference1;
  Resource2: TSomeKindOfHandleOrReference2;
  Resource3: TSomeKindOfHandleOrReference3;
begin
  AcquireResource1;
  try
    AcquireResource2;
    try
      AcquireResource3;
      try
        // Use the resources
      finally
        ReleaseResource3;
      end;
    finally
      ReleaseResource2;
    end;
  finally
    ReleaseResource1;
  end;
end;
```

and want something like

```
TDoSomething = record // or class
strict private
  Resource1: TSomeKindOfHandleOrReference1;
  Resource2: TSomeKindOfHandleOrReference2;
  Resource3: TSomeKindOfHandleOrReference3;
public
  procedure Init; // or constructor
  procedure Done; // or destructor
  procedure UseResources;
end;

procedure DoSomething;
var
  Context: TDoSomething;
begin
  Context.Init;
  try
    Context.UseResources;
  finally
    Context.Done;
  end;
end;
```

I want this to have the same exception-safety as the nested original. Is it enough to zero-initialize the ResourceN variables in `TDoSomething.Init` and do some `if Assigned(ResourceN) then` checks in `TDoSomething.Done`?

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment: If it eases your pain imagine the three nested blocks are extracted into three routines which are then called in a nested way. :-) Doesn't change the core of the issue.

Comment: Hey - where's that comment gone? :-)

Comment: It does - I removed the comment as I got over the 'OMG!' moment rather speedily as I'm not a Delphi guy, and suddenly recalled a lot worse. ;) But, I would query: why can't you simply use a single `try / finally`, determining which resource wasn't acquired, and disposing of the ones that were? I guess that's where you're headed with your approach though.

Comment: Yes. I just asked because I don't want to throw the exception-safety out of the window inadvertently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three things about classes that make this idiom safe and easy:

1. During the memory-allocation phase of the constructor (before the real constructor body runs), class-reference fields get initialized to nil.
2. When an exception occurs in a constructor, the destructor is called automatically.
3. It's always safe to call `Free` on a null reference, so you never need to check `Assigned` first.

Since the destructor can rely on all fields to have known values, it can safely call `Free` on everything, regardless of how far the constructor got before crashing. Each field will either hold a valid object reference or it will be nil, and either way, it's safe to free it.

```
constructor TDoSomething.Create;
begin
  Resource1 := AcquireResource1;
  Resource2 := AcquireResource2;
  Resource3 := AcquireResource3;
end;

destructor TDoSomething.Destroy;
begin
  Resource1.Free;
  Resource2.Free;
  Resource3.Free;
end;
```

Use it the same way you use any other class:

```
Context := TDoSomething.Create;
try
  Context.UseResources;
finally
  Context.Free;
end;
```

Comment: I can't take advantage of item 3 because ReleaseResource isn't necessarily a call to TObject.Free. But I can fix this with `if Assigned` and item 2 seems to be the important point anyway. So I'll stay with the idiomatic way and reap the benefits.

Comment: I usually put the contructor call inside the try..finally block. I just realized (per your point 2) that it is not necessary. I am unsure if I will change my habit, though, as I find it more clear. What do you think?

Comment: Follow the example of `TObject.Free` and `FreeMem` and *make* `ReleaseResource` safe to call on a null resource. It makes things so much easier everywhere else.

Comment: Not only is it not necessary, @PA, it's *wrong*. If the constructor throws, then the variable you're assigning the result to is not initialized, so you're calling `Free` on an uninitialized value.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use a single try/finally/end block for multiple resources with zero-initialization.

Another possible solution can be found in [Barry Kelly blog](http://blog.barrkel.com/2010/01/one-liner-raii-in-delphi.html)

Comment: Thanks for that idea. Some kind of guard interface already crossed my mind but it always seems overkill to me. BTW: I commented on Barry's post. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The pattern with testing on Assigned in finally is used in the Delphi source. You do kind of the same thing but I think you should move Context.Init to capture exception from Context.Init.

```
procedure DoSomething;
var
  Context: TDoSomething;
begin
  try
    Context.Init;
    Context.UseResources;
  finally
    Context.Done;
  end;
end;
```

**Edit 1** This is how you should do it without Context.Init and Context.Done. If you place all AquireResource code before `try` you will not free Resource1 if you get an exception in AcquireResource2

```
procedure DoSomething;
var
    Resource1: TSomeKindOfHandleOrReference1;
    Resource2: TSomeKindOfHandleOrReference2;
    Resource3: TSomeKindOfHandleOrReference3;
begin
    Resource1 := nil;
    Resource2 := nil;
    Resource3 := nil;
    try
        AcquireResource1;
        AcquireResource2;
        AcquireResource3;

        //Use the resources

    finally
        if assigned(Resource1) then ReleaseResource1;
        if assigned(Resource2) then ReleaseResource2;
        if assigned(Resource3) then ReleaseResource3;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Hmm, putting the Init inside the try block seems wrong. Do you propose that because I made TDoSomething a record type. If it were a class would you write `try Context := TDoSomething.Create;`?

Comment: It seems wrong because it *is* wrong. If initialization throws an exception, you don't want to finalize anything because you won't know what's safe to finalize.

Comment: @Mikael: That's probably the same issue as in http://stackoverflow.com/q/398137/35162. I remember there were a lot discussions about **very** subtle points. ;-)

Comment: @Ulrich - Yes, the accepted answer is the same as I suggests. Does this mean that your question should be marked as duplicate :)  ?

Comment: No, Mikael, the accepted answer there is *not* the same as what you've shown here. If `AcquireResource2` throws an exception, `Resource2` and `Resource3` will not be initialized yet, so it is an error to check their current values with `Assigned`. You need to initialize things *before* entering a `try` block.

Comment: @Rob - I will update with the necessary initialization code. From the question I assumed that was being done in Init. "Is it enough to zero-initialize the ResourceN variables in TDoSomething.Init"

Comment: @Mikael: I must admit that my question looks quite like a duplicate in retrospective.

Comment: @Mikael: I accepted Rob's answer because it looks more idiomatic/Delphi'ish and is probably what the language designers *want* me to write. Thank you for your input!